# How to correctly create promise that resolves when webhook is called

Tags: node.js, promise

I just watched James Snell's excellent talk on Promises in Node: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XV-u_Ow47s0

This got me thinking about a piece of code I have that calls a web service, supplying a webhook URL, which I'm sure is suboptimal. But I don't know how I should write this correctly. To paraphrase my code:

```js
const activeRequests = new Map();

function makeRequest(id:string) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    fetch(`http://external.com/someComplexCalculation`,
      { 
        method:"POST",
        body: { webhook:`http://myservice.com/webhook/${id}` }
      })
    .then(res => {
      activeRequests.set(id, resolve);
    });
  });
}

expressApp.post('/webhook/:id', (req, res) => {
  const active = activeRequests.get(req.params.id);
  if (active) {
    active();
  }
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

I've skipped all the error handling for clarity, but you get the idea. Is this the best way to do this? The end goal is for the caller of `makeRequest` to receive a promise that will resolve when the webhook is called.

The expected flow is that my application calls `await makeRequest(xx)` which calls some external service - that service then calls back to my application via the `/webhook/xx` URL when it is done with its processing, at which point the original makeRequest promise resolves.

I currently store the `resolve` function from the new Promise in a Map since I can't call that resolve function until the webhook is invoked, but that is the crux of my question: is there a better way to achieve this that doesn't involve this odd arrangement?

Comment: What you've posted doesn't seem to fit together - when does `makeRequest` get called? Why do you create a `new Promise` wrapping the promise that `fetch` already returns?

Comment: Thanks for the note - edited the description to clarify these questions.